# How to append the same parameter for multiple identical login pages if authentication fails?

Tags: spring-security

I have the same login form on different endpoints: `/welcome`, 
 `/login`

If I set failureUrl(`/welcome?error`) it will redirect the `/login` to `/welcome?error` as well if authentication fails instead of `/login?error`

I think I need to implement a failureHandler, but how can I extract the actual login endpoint from HttpServletRequest?

I would like to something like that: 
`response.sendRedirect(/[actual_login_endpoint]?error);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I had to send a hidden attribute with the login forms. I don't think there is an easier solution.

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response,
        final AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (request.getParameter("loginForm").equals("welcome")) {
        response.sendRedirect("/welcome?error");
    } else if (request.getParameter("loginForm").equals("login")) {
        response.sendRedirect("/login?error");
    }
}
```